# Visibility of network traffic in Teamviewer

Tags: network, teamviewer

I intend to use public wifi to access my home computer from the local library.

I was wondering if I remote login to my home computer using Teamviewer on a compromised wifi, will a hacker be able to see the contents of the Teamviewer traffic to my home desktop or just traffic.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is made under the assumption that TeamViewer uses a secure connection with remote host/peer validation.

Source: https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-secure-is-TeamViewer/ta-p/4619

If the TeamViewer client correctly verifies the remote host and no invalid remote host error or warning is given, we can conclude the connection is secure and is not subject to a mitm attack.

However, it seems that TeamViewer is using self-developed key-exchange and remote host validation mechanisms and is not using open and popular algorithms like TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.

Because the implementation is an important factor we cannot be completely sure a mitm attack is impossible.